# download file from azure storage with token get from msal in angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal, sas-token

I build application in angular that need to download files from azure storage account according to authorization of users in AAD.
I used msal to authenticate the user and get token from it but i don't know how to use this token in order to download files from azure storage ,i try to follow the sample code of how to use that tokens in storage account in asp.net https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet#view-and-run-the-completed-sample
but I found it very difficult to the the adjustments in order to make it work in angular,

i also tried different approach involving sas token and build server in node and express to authenticate the users and after it pass to my angular client a sas tokens but i didnt manage to understand how i do it well and further more  how I give different access permission to users like i can do in AAD and rbac,i understand there is type of sas that called delegated user but i didn't understand how make it in use.

so what the best practice in order to download files from azure-storage with different access permission to different user in angular prefer using AAD?

i really desperate from try to understand how to do it and work for it almost a month ,I'll apricate any help ,
regards,
gal

Comment: Have you go throuth this doc about Azure AD auth for Azure storage account? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json let me know if you have any questions

Comment: yes i did , but this doc doesn't explain who to interface storage account with angular or with code at all.

Comment: I see , so you are looking for some TypeScript code demo that using an Azure AD access token to download files from Azure storage?

Comment: yes, and proper way to acquire the token till now i am using msal, furthermore I want to know if authenticate and access to azure storage in my angular client app is the best practice in meaning of security  or to build server in node to authenticate the user is prefer.

Comment: yes it did it i  another post that i rephrase my question tmx :)